# Error in code for inserting an element in an array

Tags: arrays, c

Here I have written a code that accepts an array of any size suitable to the user from a user agrees with a place to insert a new integer in the collection and coordinates with the integer to be inserted.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void insert(int barray_size, int *A, int new_place, int new_int)
{
    for (int i = barray_size; i >= new_place; i = i - 1)
    {
        *(A + i) = *(A + i - 1); //copies value of cell A[i-1] to cell A[i]
        *(A + i - 1) = 0; //empties cell A[i-1] so that it can take the value A[i-2] in next loop
    }

    *(A + new_place - 1) = new_int; //putting the required integer at A[k]
}

int main()
{
    int n, k, l;
    printf("Please enter array size: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("\n");
    int A[n + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int temp;
        printf("Enter [%d] element: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &temp);
        A[i] = temp;
        printf("\n");
    }

    A[n] = 0;
    printf("Enter the place where new integer is to be inserted: ");
    scanf("%d", &k);

    if (k < n + 1)
    {
        printf("Enter the integer to be inserted: ");
        scanf("%d", &l);
        int t = n + 1;
        insert(t, A, k, l);
        printf("The new array is: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < t; ++i)
        {
            printf("%d ", A[i]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Please enter a valid address.");
    }
}
```

But when I run this code, it terminates after accepting place for integer but does not accept the integer to be inserted.
Would you mind helping in detecting the error?

***THANK YOU***

*Edit 1*: Corrected the trivial error of address in scanf.

Now the program more or less adds the integer in the array properly (although at place `k + 1` if requested at `k`, but that can be corrected). But it prints all the values of the array beyond `A[i + 1]` with garbage values, despite using the for loop in the end which should have stopped printing the loop at `A[n + 1]`. Why is this happening?

(I apologize if my doubts are trivial or silly. I have started learning C language very recently and due to lack of practice, I am prone to such trivial errors and require help for clarification of such doubts while practicing, which I seek at SO)

*Edit 2:* After initializing `A[n] = 0`, which was missing before, the program works perfectly and terminates properly.

Thanks to everybody for helping out.

Comment: `int A[n+1];` you have not yet assigned a value to `n`. You need to allocate space for the array after you accept a value for `n`.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Edited and corrected. But the program still terminates at the same place.

Comment: Imagine how much easier this would be to read if you used meaningful variables names instead of `insert(t, A, k, l);`. It appears the `insert` function indexes outside the bounds of the allocated array. Consider not adding `+1` here: `int t=n+1;` It may still go outside the bounds, but I'm done trying to read this. Just know that for an array `int someArray[10];` the valid indices are 0 - 9.

Comment: You are also assuming that the entires from the user are valid. What if the user decides to create an array of size 10 and then decides to insert a new integer at location 2000. That should not be allowed as it will be out of bounds for the array.

Comment: @whiplash I'm sorry for that. I've tried to rectify that error by an if-else statement. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to specify the address of the variable `k` and `l` in `scanf` and your

Change:

```
scanf("%d", k);
scanf("%d", l);
```

To:

```
scanf("%d", &k);
scanf("%d", &l);
```

Change:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n+1; i++)
```

To:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

Here down is modified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void insert(int arrSize, int *A, int newPlace, int newInt)
{
    for(int i = arrSize; i > newPlace; i = i - 1)
    {
        *(A + i) = *( A + (i - 1));
        *(A + (i - 1)) = 0; 
    }
    *(A + newPlace) = newInt; 
}

int main()
{
    int no, place, newdata;
    printf("Please enter array size: ");
    scanf("%d", &no);
    printf("\n");
    int arr[no];
    for (int index = 0; index < no; index++)
    {
        int temp;
        printf("Enter [%d] element: ", index);
        scanf("%d", &temp);
        arr[index] = temp;
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    printf("Enter the place where new integer is to be inserted: ");
    scanf("%d", &place);
    
    if(place < no)
    {
        printf("Enter the integer to be inserted: ");
        scanf("%d", &newdata);
        
        insert(no, arr, place, newdata);
        printf("The new array is: ");
        for (int index2 = 0; index2 <= no; index2++)
        {
            printf("%d ", arr[index2]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Please enter a valid address.");
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Please enter array size: 7

Enter [0] element: 1

Enter [1] element: 2

Enter [2] element: 3

Enter [3] element: 4

Enter [4] element: 5

Enter [5] element: 6

Enter [6] element: 7

Enter the place where new integer is to be inserted: 5
Enter the integer to be inserted: 10
The new array is: 1 2 3 4 5 10 6 7
```

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. Corrected the address issue.

Comment: @DevanshKamra Check my modified answer

Comment: I checked your code on an online compiler with array size = 7 and new_place=5 and new_place=4, but in both cases it shows "Please enter a valid address."

Comment: It now works perfectly. I guess it was not working when we use either n+1 in comparison, or sizeof(n). Thanks for helping out!

Comment: This might just be a niche thing but your statement in `else` should be `Entered address is not valid. It should be between 0 and n` and not `Please enter a valid address.` This is because your error message is not in a loop so the user will not have the choice of entering a valid address unless he re-runs the program.

Comment: `int A[n - 1];` declares an array too small to hold all of the values input by the `for` loop right after it. Passing `n + 1` to the `insert` function makes it worse. https://godbolt.org/z/7b7GbEhrK

Answer (score 1):

In your code, when you do `scanf("%d", )`, you need to pass in the address of the variable. Not the variable itself. Can you try the following and see if it works:

```
int main()
{
    // CODE TO READ ARRAY AS YOU HAVE ALREADY WRITTEN
    printf(("Enter the place where new integer is to be inserted: ");
    scanf("%d", &k); // CHANGE HERE from k to &k
    printf("Enter the integer to be inserted: ");
    scanf("%d", &l); // CHANGE HERE FROM l to &l
    /* CHANGE HERE. 
    You don't need n+1 because when you create an array of size n+1, the indices are from 0 to n. 
    You are reading values only for 0 to n-1 in your loop.
    In your insert function, you are starting at i=n which is the last free space in the array.
    */
    insert(n, A, k, l)
    // REST OF YOUR CODE TO PRINT THE ARRAY
}
```